# Rangy how to expand without symbols?

Tags: javascript, regex, range, rangy

I'm trying to de-select the punctuation symbols that appear before or after a selection and use the word expand function. For example I have this annotation:

> (56.87%)**, α-cad**inol  (Bold text is highlighted text ","  is included)

I try to get the following:

> (56.87%), **α-cadinol**  (Bold text is highlighted text)

I've tried the following method:

```
        var sel = rangy.getSelection();
        var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);

        var selectedText = range.text();
        // Trim start
        var match = /^\s*\.*\,*\"*\'*\;*\“*\-*\s*/.exec(selectedText);
        if (match) {
            range.moveStart("character", match[0].length);
        }

        // Trim end
        match = /\s*\.*\,*\"*\'*\;*\”*\-*\s*$/.exec(selectedText);
        if (match) {
            range.moveEnd("character", -match[0].length);
        }
        sel.setSingleRange(range);

        sel.expand("word", {
            trim: true
        });
```

But not working properly. The first part alone works, but with the second it not work, because it results in the following:

> (56.87 **%), α-cadinol**  (Bold text is highlighted text)

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks good. The issue is that the default regular expression that Rangy uses to determine what constitutes a word is very simplistic. Fortunately you can override it in the options you pass to expand. The example here is also intended just as a starting point to solve the immediate problem; it's obviously too simplistic for general use but should serve as a starting point.

```
sel.expand("word", {
    trim: true,
    wordOptions: {
        wordRegex: /[a-z0-9α]+(['\-][a-z0-9α]+)*/gi
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. However the problem is that it is taking the symbols that precede the word. Like %), when it selects is only the " ,α-cadinol". I think that the problem is not the alpha character. I'll try to fix it with a more complex expression. Thanks!!

Comment: @Martin: Yes, you'll still need your existing stuff to strip the punctuation. Sorry, I should have been clearer. The alpha character definitely is a problem for the `expand()` call. See the following for a comparison: http://jsbin.com/cepisexuco/1

Comment: It works! But for unknown reasons it did not work for me. But it is the solution. Thanks.( I have last version of Rangy)

Comment: I think I detected the problem. I think chrome browser, select letters're not really choosing. For example, in the last instance, if I start selected in the "," symbol chrome says that i selected also the parentheses.